How to delete orphaned devices in AAD?
In Intune, Entra, how can I find and delete orphaned devices, where the primary UPN is deleted? I also need to remove them from Autopilot. Has someone got a powershell script?

You can use below script to find and delete orphaned devices with no primary UPN.
First install these modules
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo -Force
Install-Module MSOnline

check this document
Once you are connected, you should see something like below, same how they showed in the doc above.

and connect to Microsoft Graph for Intune as per this doc
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All"

And this will be your script-
# Thhis will get your devices
$aadDevices = Get-AzureADDevice

# this will filter devices where the UPN is not assigned
$orphanedDevices = $aadDevices | Where-Object { $_.DeviceOwnerType -eq 'Personal' -and -not $_.ObjectId }

$orphanedDevices


You can remove these orphaned devices using their ObjectId
$orphanedDevices | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureADDevice -ObjectId $_.ObjectId }

Similar way for Intune
$intuneDevices | ForEach-Object { Remove-MgDeviceManagementManagedDevice -ManagedDeviceId $_.Id }

And for autopilot

$autopilotDevices = Get-WindowsAutopilotDeviceInfo

$orphanedAutopilotDevices = $autopilotDevices | Where-Object { $_.AssignedUser -eq $null }

$orphanedAutopilotDevices | ForEach-Object { Remove-WindowsAutopilotDevice -DeviceId $_.DeviceId }

You can also refer to this document  for reference
